# Formula for exponentially increasing series

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Given $a,$ $n,$ and $b$ are all constants, how would one solve for $x$ in the exponentially increasing series?

Here is the formula:

$$x+x(a)+x(a^2)+x(a^3)+...x(a^n) = b$$

Comment: Look up “geometric series.” There are standard formulas for them. The one you have is a finite geometric series (that is, it has a finite number of terms in the sum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factor out the $x$.

To sum $1 + a + \cdots + a^n$ in closed form, think about how to factor $a^{n+1} -1$.

Comment: so what is the plugin formula?

Comment: The sum of the powers of $a$ is $(a^{n+1}-1)/(a-1)$. After that it's elementary algebra to get your "plugin formula".